# Expo Web + Reanimated: Metro error: requestAnimationFrame is not defined

Tags: expo, react-native-reanimated, metro-bundler, react-native-reanimated-v2, expo-web

This error prevented me from building my expo app for web (`npx expo export -p web`)

It seems this error only happens in expo SDK 49+

Here is a screenshot of the console logs, has you see stack trace is of no help at all:

[image]

Other than that I am using the default metro config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after some days of work .

I just needed to `npm install raf` (requestAnimationFrame polyfill) and add those two lines to the `metro.config.js`:

```js
const raf = require('raf')
raf.polyfill()
```

The `metro.config.js` may not exist, in this case you can create it according to [this expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/metro/)